# Airflow - Druid Operator is not getting host

Tags: airflow, druid, airflow-webserver, airflow-api

I have a question for Druid Operator. I see that this test is successful, but I take a this error.

> File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 792, in get_adapter
> raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")

I take a dag like this

```
DRUID_CONN_ID = "druid_ingest_conn_id"
 ingestion = DruidOperator(
    task_id='ingestion',
    druid_ingest_conn_id=DRUID_CONN_ID,
    json_index_file='ingestion.json'
)
```

Also I change the dag to look overload but I take same error.

Another step I change the type to like this but I have a different error

```
    ingestion_2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='test_task',
    method='POST',
    http_conn_id=DRUID_CONN_ID,
    endpoint='/druid/indexer/v1/task',
    data=json.dumps(read_file),
    dag=dag,
    do_xcom_push=True,
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    response_check=lambda response: response.json()['Status'] == 200,
)
```

> {"error":"Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.indexing.common.task.Task]: missing type id property 'type'\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 1]"}

Finally I try giving Http connection in Druid Operator but I have a error like this

> raise AirflowException(f'Did not get 200 when submitting the Druid job to {url}')

So that I am confused. I need a help. Thanks for answers.

P.S: We use 2.3.3 Airflow version

Comment: P.S I updated Airflow v2.4.0 but I didn't work :(

Comment: Are you using the Druid Provider? I can't find the reference, but I recall reading about a potential bug. The workaround was to set the Airflow connection to HTTP instead of Druid.

Comment: Yes we are using Druid Provider. We are also ingest data from curl to druid.